“Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin
I’m developing a Flutter application in Android Studio. After upgrading the Flutter version from around 2.8 to 3.19.5, the Android build on a physical device no longer works.
The error is as follows:
    e: /Users/shun/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.lifecycle/lifecycle-common/2.7.0/85334205d65cca70ed0109c3acbd29e22a2d9cb1/lifecycle-common-2.7.0.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/shun/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b268270c5f07ae84179bbcf92aab4c93/transformed/jetified-savedstate-1.2.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/savedstate_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/shun/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.24/9928532f12c66ad816a625b3f9984f8368ca6d2b/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.24.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/shun/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.24/9928532f12c66ad816a625b3f9984f8368ca6d2b/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.24.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: /Users/shun/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.9.24/9928532f12c66ad816a625b3f9984f8368ca6d2b/kotlin-stdlib-1.9.24.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

┌─ Flutter Fix 
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                                                                                        │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update /Users/shun/Downloads/workspace/mirre/android/build.gradle: │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                                                                                       │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

android/build.gradle file with:
 buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.24'
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
            classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.1'
        }
    }

flutter doctor is as follows:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.5, on macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-arm64 (Rosetta), locale ja-JP)
    • Flutter version 3.19.5 on channel stable at /Users/shun/Downloads/workspace/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 300451adae (9 weeks ago), 2024-03-27 21:54:07 -0500
    • Engine revision e76c956498
    • Dart version 3.3.3
    • DevTools version 2.31.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/shun/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34-ext8, build-tools 35.0.0-rc1
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/shun/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11572160)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15F31d
    • CocoaPods version 1.15.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11572160)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.89.1)
    • VS Code at /Users/shun/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.88.0

[✓] Connected device (6 available)
    • M2101K6G (mobile)      • 63397ca9                             • android-arm64  • Android 13 (API 33)
    • shun's iPad (mobile)     • 00008030-001944DE3682202E            • ios            • iOS 17.4.1 21E236
    • shun's (mobile)          • 00008120-000A308A1103C01E            • ios            • iOS 17.4.1 21E236
    • iPhone 15 Pro (mobile) • A21A87ED-90BB-4062-B92F-D76D7F68ED0C • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-5 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)        • macos                                • darwin-arm64   • macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-arm64 (Rosetta)
    • Chrome (web)           • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 125.0.6422.78

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

Articles suggest that changing the build.gradle file should resolve the issue, but I'm not using Kotlin version 1.6.0 anywhere in my project, which is causing confusion.
I tried change the Kotlin version in  android/ build.gradle,,,
but,it couldn't read the project.

I had the same problem a while ago, What I have done is set Kotlin version from
ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.10'

to
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'

and I have also update the target for my android devices <project_dir>/android/app/build.gradle to:
android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23 
        targetSdkVersion 34
        ...
    }
}

Explanation:

Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary
version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

This error usually occurs when there's a mismatch between the Kotlin compiler version used to compile a module and the version expected by the Kotlin runtime in your Flutter project.
The expected version is the Kotlin for kotlin-gradle-plugin and The binary version is for what is downloaded for com.android.tools.build:gradle
after doing this remove Invalidate caches and restart IDE or flutter clean and flutter run.

I had the same problem a while ago I've went to Kotlin gradle versions below is the link
Kotlin versions link
To build a Flutter app for Android, Kotlin 1.5.31 or greater is required.
You can change version of Kotlin under build.gradle file and then restart your IDE.

Try these changes
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'

And I would recommend you to check this link Flutter Gradle Plugin.
Follow the steps mentioned and run flutter clean once, should work without any issues.
